# Make the program the you if the word you've inputed in the console is a palindrome or not in Java

Tags: java, console, palindrome

I've been trying to make this program work, have the person write a word in the console and make the console have an output saying if that word is or isn't a palindrome.

```
package sct;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3Problem4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a  a string: ");
        String DAWORD = reader.nextLine();

        reader.close();

        int n = DAWORD.length();
        boolean isPalindrome = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (DAWORD.charAt(i) != DAWORD.charAt(n - i - 1)) {

                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
            if (isPalindrome)
                System.out.println("This word is a palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println("This word is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, this didn't work and the console doesn't let me input a string, can someone find out why and fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't print whether the word is a palindrome (or not) until ***after*** the `for` loop. That's the only issue I had running the posted code.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a  a string: ");
String DAWORD = reader.nextLine();

reader.close();

int n = DAWORD.length();
boolean isPalindrome = true;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (DAWORD.charAt(i) != DAWORD.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isPalindrome)
    System.out.println("This word is a palindrome");
else
    System.out.println("This word is not a palindrome");
```

You might want to remove `reader.close()` (as that **also** closes `System.in`).

Comment: Could you post the correct version of the code please?

Comment: @Love I did. This **is** the correct version of the code. I have tested it. It works. It's not the most efficient, or the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could consider is putting your input into a `StringBuilder` object, reverse it, then check if it equals your input.

Something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String DAWORD = reader.nextLine();

        reader.close();

        if (new StringBuilder(DAWORD).reverse().toString().contentEquals(DAWORD))
            System.out.println("This word is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println("This word is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Enter a string: 
racecar
This word is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an external apache lang library from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7.  Then you can use StringUtils.reverse() method which reverses a string and then compare reversed string with the normal one , like so:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Main4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "kajak";

        String str2 =StringUtils.reverse(str);
        if (str2.equals(str)){
            System.out.println("It's a palidrom");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not a palidorm");
        }

    }


}
```